# Prolog Gerrit - validate label if commit message contains a specific string

Tags: prolog, gerrit

I'm not familiar with prolog, but I tried to understand the examples I copied from the Gerrit Prolog Cookbook.

I added a NoOp label Ticket-Checked with three states -1, 0, 1.
The label must be +1 if the commit message matches a regex for submitting.
If not contained in the commit message, gerrit should simply ignore the flag.

```
submit_rule(S) :-
  gerrit:default_submit(X), % get the current submit structure
  X=.. [submit | Ls],
  require_ticket_check_for_ticket(Ls, Nls),
  S=.. [submit | Nls].

require_ticket_check_for_ticket(S1, S2) :-
   gerrit:commit_message_matches("\\[Issue-[l-9][0-9]*\\]"), !,
   S2 = [label('Ticket-Checked', need(_)) | S1]. % Add the label 

require_ticket_check_for_ticket(S1, S2) :-
   !, S2 = S1.
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow, the code doesn't work for me, just updated the `regex` of `gerrit:commit_message_matches` and works:

```
submit_rule(S) :-
    gerrit:default_submit(X),
    X =.. [submit | Ls],
    require_ticket_check_for_ticket(Ls, Nls),
    S =.. [submit | Nls].

require_ticket_check_for_ticket(S1, S2) :-
    gerrit:commit_message_matches('^issue-[\\d]+\\s?:\\s?[\\w\\W]+'),
    !,
    S2 = [label('Ticket-Checked', need(_)) | S1].

require_ticket_check_for_ticket(S1, S2) :-
    !, S2 = S1.
```

btw, it will be better to use `ok(user(ID))` to handle the validation, since the validation rules (`^issue-[\\d]+\\s?:\\s?[\\w\\W]+`) already added in the `rules.pl`, so, change `label('Ticket-Checked', need(_)` to `label('Ticket-Checked', ok(user(<ID>)))`.

Comment: haha, just after 6 years :) I saw there has been an l in the regex besides a 1